# range.select fails on IE10 to properly highlight text

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have an application that loops thru a textarea, searching for specific text, highlighting it if found, and prompting the user whether to act upon the found text.  This has worked fine on all versions of IE prior to IE10 (the text is highlighted, and the user is prompted).

With IE10, the range.select will no longer highlight the text, due to what appears to be the CONFIRM prompt.  If CONFIRM is removed, the text is highlighted.  Also on IE 10, after the last CONFIRM is OK'd, the last instance of the text is then highlighted when the form returns to focus.

Below is a code snippet that will work demonstrate this, and will work fine under IE 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, but will fail on IE10.  Any help on redesigning or other code alternatives would be greatly appreciated.  I ONLY need this to work in the IE environment (internal application, limited to IE only use).

---

```
<html>
<body>

<form name="theForm">
   <textarea name="message" rows="20" cols="80">NAM/JONES  NAM/SMITH   NAM/BROWN</textarea>
</form>

<script>
   var message = document.theForm.message.value.toUpperCase();
   var range = document.theForm.message.createTextRange();

   for (x=0; x<message.length-1; x++) {
      if (message.substr(x,4) == "NAM/") {
         var strFound=range.findText("NAM/");
         if (strFound) range.select();
         range.collapse(false);
         msg = "Process this name?";
         if (confirm(msg)) {
            // use x.substr to extract name, and do something
         }
      }
   }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Comment: What do other browsers do? I'm guessing the confirm modal window gets focused which removes the visual focus from the range. This sounds acceptable to me. You could consider implementing your own modal window that doesn't steal focus (but really: it should)

Comment: Haven't tested it with other browsers... we're IE centric for this environment.  Unfortunatley, since I'm looping thru each found item, I need a way to pause the script, and wait for input.  This somewhat needs the confirm window to have the focus?  But, may just have to use another form of modal input to achieve this.  Too bad it worked previously....

Comment: what is f12 saying? how about setting up a submit button instead of a confirm prompt? reading about textRangeSelect atm, but i'm not sure its what you need http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536735(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I'll give the F12 developer tools a view, and see what it says.  Unfortunately, a button really wouldn't work in this fashion.  The user does press a button to initiate the textarea search, but the code then needs to read/loop thru the textarea, prompting them for each occurence of the NAM found.  Looks like maybe I'll have to find another type of modal prompt, that will allow the screen the ability to upate and show the highlighted text.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had simmilar problems and i made a demo based on yours and the problematic code we had

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
</head>
<body>

    <form name="theForm">
        <input type="text" id="txt" value="1234567890" />
        <span id="selected" />
    </form>

    <script>
        function selectRange(start, end) {
            var range = document.theForm.txt.createTextRange();
            range.moveStart("character", 0 - end);
            range.moveEnd("character", 0 - end);
            range.select();
            // Und dann den neu hinzugekommenen Teil markieren.
            range.moveStart("character", start);
            range.moveEnd("character", end - start);
            range.select();
        }
        function step(x) {
            if (x >= document.theForm.txt.value.length - 2)
                return;
            selectRange(x, x + 2);
            document.getElementById("selected").innerHTML = document.selection.createRange().text;
            window.setTimeout(function () { step(x + 1); }, 1000);
        }
        step(0);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

it turned out that `range.select();` works again when its happening inside a `setTimeout()`.

we ended up putting our problematic function into a settimeout completely

```
this.selectTextRange = function (start, end) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        var range = thisControl.textBox.createTextRange();
        // Ganz an den Anfang moven     
        range.moveStart("character", 0 - end);
        range.moveEnd("character", 0 - end);
        range.select();
        // Und dann den neu hinzugekommenen Teil markieren.
        range.moveStart("character", start);
        range.moveEnd("character", end - start);
        range.select();
    }, 0);
};
```

i hope this helps.